# How to get the height at which to draw a strikethrough from FreeType

Tags: freetype, strikethrough, fontmetrics

FreeType has font metrics for the underline position, but I can't seem to find any metrics for the strikethrough position. How do text engines usually compute this value? Should I just put it at 1/3*ascent or whatever looks good? I suppose that for Latin at least this should be 1/2*height of "m" but I'm looking for a more general solution.

Answer (score 1):

This information is not provided for all the various font formats supported by Freetype; so it is not exposed on the "main" interface.

In the (common but not universal) case of TrueType or OpenType fonts it can be retrieved in the [TT_OS2](https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-truetype_tables.html#tt_os2) table, fields `yStrikeoutSize` and `yStrikeoutPosition`; you should be prepared for the table to be lacking, or `yStrikeoutSize` to be null or negative thus unusable.

I do not remember of an equivalent for plain Postscript fonts (`.pfb`/`.pfa`, even in `.afm`.)
The various bitmap formats might have the information available; an example is `strike_out` in [Windows FNT](https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-winfnt_fonts.html#ft_winfnt_headerrec); notice this is the position, while the size defaults to be the same as underlining. Basically every format is alone here.